# How to get result to milliseconds

Tags: c

This results in microseconds being displayed how would I get it to display in milliseconds? current output is 34.0000?????

```
double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y);

int main()
{  
int i;

struct timeval before , after;
gettimeofday(&before , NULL);

//Time taking task
for (i=1 ; i <= 100 ; i++)
{
    printf("%d %d %d n",i, i*i, i*i*i);
}

gettimeofday(&after , NULL);

printf(" time elapsed : %.0lf" , time_diff(before , after) ); 

return 0;
 }

double time_diff(struct timeval x , struct timeval y)
{
    double x_ms , y_ms , diff;

x_ms = (double)x.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)x.tv_usec;
y_ms = (double)y.tv_sec*1000000 + (double)y.tv_usec;

diff = (double)y_ms - (double)x_ms;

return diff;
 }
```

Would I just want to multiply by only 1000???

Comment: I think you need to rephrase your question to make it easier to understand. What exact result are you after?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you try to use some construction not designed to measure time in seconds or ms. Try this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

double time_diff(double x , double y);

int main()
{  
   int i;

   double before;
   before = clock();

   //Time taking task
   for (i=1 ; i <= 100 ; i++)
   {
       printf("%d %d %d n",i, i*i, i*i*i);
   }

    printf("\n\ntime elapsed : %.8lf", time_diff(before, clock())); 

   return 0;
 }


double time_diff(double x , double y)
{
    return ((y - x)/CLOCKS_PER_SEC) * 100;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Divide the result by 1000 to get in milliseconds.

Comment: so  just do diff= diff/1000 then return diff?

Comment: Yes... but not sure why you want to convert to milli seconds?